# How can RabbitMQ's (Pika) unack redelivery time be increased?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

How can RabbitMQ's (Pika) unack redelivery time be increased? We have a long running task that takes longer than the default redelivery time, and so when it tries to ack once the processing is finished, it's causing an `unable to send ack` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're running into the channel ack timeout that is discussed in full here - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pull/2990#issuecomment-1002089576

Long-running tasks like yours should publish the message being worked on to another queue representing in-progress work (perhaps a queue per worker), then ack the original message. When the work completes, consume and ack the message in the in-progress queue, and re-consume from the original queue.

Yes it is more work but the channel ack timeout was introduced for a very good reason. If you know you won't run into the issue described, you *can* increase the timeout in RabbitMQ's configuration.